# How to only show the content of the view on page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I want to disable everything on the page (logo, blocks, bottom-menu,...) and only show the content of the view.

With views-view.tpl.php is not really working...

Answer (score 1):

You should create a vies page & give a path for that page e.g. - myViews.

Copy your page.tpl.php & rename it to something like page--myViews.php.

Remove everything like all the rendered block, logo, header etc which is not needed by you & render only the "content" region & it should work for you.

Comment: That's not quite right...a view is not a node, it's a view - it doesn't have a node ID. You should use this method, but call the template file `page--myViews.tpl.php` based on the path being `myViews`